# Generated component from angularcli not rendering template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, angular-components

I can see the selector in Chrome Developer tools when I serve the site and inspect the page, but html within the template is not appearing. The component was added directly from angular cli and all I did was add the opening/closing selector tags to the index.html file. There are no errors in the console.

Here is what I am seeing in the Chrome DOM:

```
<body>
<app-header></app-header>
<app-root></app-root>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

footer.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

footer.component.html

```
<p>
  footer works!
</p>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Running:
npm version 5.5.1
Angular 5.1.0
angular cli 1.6.0

Using ng-serve from command line in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: check your console and post the issue

Comment: did you add your component in you app.module.ts?

Comment: There are no issues in the console to post. Forgot to mention - will add to original post.

The angular cli generated component was automatically added to app.module.ts, yes.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just hidden with some CSS? Check the DOM in the dev tools.

Comment: I did check the DOM in Chrome Developer Tool as stated. The only thing appearing are the opening/closing selector tags. I actually created two components, one manually and one with the cli and both are exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: oops you should add your 
<app-header></app-header> and
<app-footer></app-footer>

in app.component.html not in index.html

Comment: @RoweldeGuzman I knew I was going to feel like an idiot when I found out what the problem was. You are indeed correct and that worked perfectly. If you would care to repost your comment as an answer, hopefully this will allow me to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops you should add your

```
<app-header></app-header> 
and 
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

in app.component.html not in index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your `AppModule`'s `bootstrap` array has `[AppComponent]` in it. This is how an Angular app starts. You bootstrap the one module `AppModule` and in the module's bootstrap array, there's `AppComponent`. So whatever in `<app-root></app-root>` will be where your Angular App gets rendered.

You might wanna put `<app-header></app-header>` and `<app-footer></app-footer>` inside your App.component.html

Comment: Show your: App.module.ts, app.component.ts, app.component.html

Comment: Added to original post.